# How can I access member variables of a vector of objects that is a member variable from a class?

Tags: c++, oop, object, pointers, vector

I do know how to access member variables given a vector of objects but suppose

if I have a class called "layer" that is

```
class layer{
    public: 
        layer(.... that initializes "val" .... ); 
        vector<vector<double>> getval(){return val;}
    private:
        vector<vector<double>> val; 
}
```

and then suppose there is another class that is

```
class Net{
    public:
        Net( ..... that initializes "nn" ..... ); 
        vector<layer> getnn(){ return nn; }
    private:
        vector<layer> nn; 
}
```

So in the main function, I could create an object like

```
Net n( ....... )
```

and in the main function I could get vector of objects via

```
n.getnn();
```

but the question is how could I get the specific, given i index,

```
vector<vector<double>> val
```

at nn[i]

Comment: Unrelated: Is it intentional that `getval()` and `getnn()` always returns a copy of the members?

Comment: what are all those `....` ? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question. You seem to be aware that `std::vector` has a `operator[]` to access elements like `nn[i]`. To access a specific layer, you can do `layer l = n.getnn()[i]`. Then, you can access a specific value using `l.getval()[k][l]`. Is there something else? (PS.: As said in the previous comment, be aware that this implementation make a lot of copies and can significantly slow down computations.)

Comment: oh, inside the class Net, I could do layer l = n.getnn()[i] ...etc but in the main function, how would I go about doing that? if I create an object in the main function and go like layer l = n.getnn()[i] then it tells me that getnn() function is not part of class Net

Comment: Also, if I want to directly return the members, then I would do return this->val ... etc? since it directly points to the members, it wouldn't create a copy of the said members, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
float value = n.getnn()[i].getval()[j][k];
```

Comment: Care to explain your code please, and how it solves the problem (which is still unclear BTW).

Comment: Ohhhhh that's what I was looking for. It kinda makes sense.

Comment: So my implementation is passing copies of members and values, so I should use pointers whenever I could? like in class Layer, I should change to getval(){ return this->val; } ? will this improve speed?